# Subprocess doesn't open the correct directory

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running a script which prompts the user to select a directory, saves a plot to that directory and then uses subprocess to open that location:

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please    select a directory')
fig.savefig(dirname+'/XXXXXX.png',dpi=300)
plt.close("all")
root.withdraw()

subprocess.Popen('explorer dirname')
```

When I run the file I select a sub-directory in D:\Documents and the figure save is correct. However the subprocess simply opens D:\Documents as opposed to D:\Documents\XXX.

Ben

Comment: Do you actually have `subprocess.Popen('explorer dirname')` in your code, or is it a typo and you have `subprocess.Popen(['explorer', dirname])` instaed (`dirname` outside quotes)?

Comment: As with most things (being an engineer and a very amateur programmer) I googled "how to open directory python" And using subprocess was one of the first links that came up. What should I have done??

Comment: Evert: subprocess.Popen('explorer dirname') is directly in the code

Comment: I just want to launch the directory that the image  is saved into because the main thing I will do with the output is drag the image into a .pptx doc so it's quicker to launch the folder in explorer

Comment: @BMichell, try `check_call(["explorer", os.path.normpath(dirname)])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only passing the string `'dirname'` not the variable that you have named dirname in your code. Since you (presumably) don't have a directory called dirname on your system, explorer opens the default (Documents).

You may also have a problem with / vs \ in directory names. As shown in comments, use os.path module to convert to the required one.

You want something like

```
import os
win_dir = os.path.normpath(dirname)
subprocess.Popen('explorer "%s"' %win_dir)
```

or

```
import os
win_dir = os.path.normpath(dirname) 
subprocess.Popen(['explorer', win_dir])
```

Comment: Both of those still go to D:\Documents

Comment: @BMichell have you checked that the directory stored in `dirname` is correct?

Comment: Yes I've done print dirname and copied the result into the statement as: subprocess.Popen('explorer "D:\Documents\XXXXX"') and it works fine

Comment: XXXX doesn't include spaces does it? Try putting it in quotes; I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ok correction if I print dirname it gives the filename with / not \ if I copy this pat it doesn't work. If I copy the path from windows explorer manually with \ It works fine.

Comment: So looks like the issue is the files path is returned with / how can I specify that these should be \. Could do a string replacement, but seems a bit long-winded.

Comment: based on what @Padraic said above, I've added a possible fix although I've not got a windows machine to try it on.

Comment: don't use quotes if you pass the path as a list argument. `subprocess`  adds quotes if there are spaces in the argument.

Answer (score 2):

To open a directory with the default file explorer:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open(dirname) #NOTE: no quotes around the name
```

It might use `os.startfile(dirname)` on Windows.

If you want to call `explorer.exe` explicitly:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['explorer', dirname]) #NOTE: no quotes
```

`dirname` is a variable. `'dirname'` is a string literal that has no relation to the `dirname` name.

Answer (score -1):

Add ,Shell=True after 'explorer dirname'
If Shell is not set to True, then the commands you want to implement must be in list form (so it would be ['explorer', ' dirname']. You can also use shlex which helps a lot if you don't want to make Shell = True and don't want to deal with lists.

Edit: Ah I miss read the question. often you need a direct path to the directory, so that may help.

Comment: Looks that way - if I type the path directly it works fine. Is there a way of evaluating the statement (spot the ex-Matlab user....) to not have to type the path manually?

Comment: Sadly, I am not sure. But it would be incredibly useful! If you find an answer I would love to hear it!